# Does a horizontal bundle on a fibre bundle induce an affine linear connexion on its tangent bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\pi:E\to B$ be a (locally trivial, and smooth) fibre bundle whose fibres are diffeomorphic to $F$, and $\mathcal{H}\subset TE$ be a subbundle satisfying $TE=\mathcal{V}\oplus\mathcal{H}$, where $\mathcal{V}\subset TE$ is the integrable subbundle whose leaves are exactly the fibres (the vertical subbundle).

> Does a choice of such a horizontal bundle $\mathcal{H}\subset TE$ (or any other equivalent description of a connexion) induce an affine linear connexion on the tangent bundle of the total space of the fibre bundle, $TE$ ? If it is so, how the construction goes?

I am aware of what happens when the fibre bundle is a principal fibre bundle or a vector bundle, I am not interested in these situations, though; e.g. $F$ can be diffeomorphic to a two dimensional sphere.

I tried to mimic Bott's construction having in mind that the fibre bundle is just an example of a foliation, but I could not end with an affine linear connexion on the tangent space of the total space $E$... I would expect this, as his construction only provides an affine linear connexion on $TE/\mathcal{V}$. Another attempt was to use just the notion of parallel transport (here I find it also difficult to recover an affine linear connexion even assuming that the fibre bundle is a vector bundle, although I can work this out).